# How to restrict imports from sibling directories using an eslint rule?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, eslintrc

I have a mono repo style codebase where I build several separate applications that have a shared codebase. I want an eslint rule that errors if one app tries to import from another app.

My file structure looks like this:

```
/src/App1  
/src/App2  
/src/App3  
/src/Shared  
/.eslintrc.json  
/package.json
```

Comment: Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not.